# How can I access the data in the result of a call to a Neo4j database using the new .Net driver?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, neo4j

I am using the new neo4j 3.0 RC1 and trying to create a simple .net MVC app that will manipulate a local neo4j database.

I can create nodes and retrieve them, using cypher and the driver, but I am not sure what to do with the result when I receive it.

Say I wanted to print a list of the people in this database, showing their names and ages, how do I access the data (in the controller or view)?

Here is my code:

```
session.Run("MERGE (father:Person {name: 'Paul', age: 45})");
session.Run("MERGE (mother:Person {name: 'Julia', age: 43})");
session.Run("MERGE (son:Person {name: 'Hugo', age: 5})");
session.Run("MERGE (daughter:Person {name: 'Mary', age: 7})");
var result = session.Run("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p");
```

The result is No4j.Driver.Internal.Result.StatementResult (an IStatementResult) and it contains items Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Result.Record, when I foreach over it.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: did you check the driver documentation? http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0-RC1/#results

Answer (score 4):

You would put something like:

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
    //Get as an INode instance to access properties.
    var node = r["p"].As<INode>();

    //Properties are a Dictionary<string,object>, so you need to 'As' them
    var age = node["age"].As<int>();
    var name = node["name"].As<string>();

    Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {age} years old.");
}
```